# Accessing orm data in a node express post callback

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, orm, routes

I try to set up a JSON API with Express 4.14.0 (orm 3.1.0 / mySQL) In the app.js I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var data = require('./model/datamodel');
var api = require('./routes/api');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', api);

module.exports = app;
```

I use datamodel.js for setting up the orm:

```
var express = require('express');
var orm = require('orm');
var app = express();

app.use(orm.express("mysql://onserver:>2hZ[RpfCT~!xx@localhost/onserver", {
    define: function (db, models, next) {
        models.person = db.define("person", { 
            name      : String,
            surname   : String,
        } );

        next();
    }   
}));
```

And api.js for the actual api:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();    

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({ message: 'hoorayDATABASE: undefined! welcome to our api!' });  
});

router.route( "/main" ).post( function( req, res ) { 
    console.log( "MODELS:", req.models );  
            // req.models is undefined
            // I want to access req.models.person.find( ... )
})

module.exports = router;
```

I call `localhost:3000/main` and I receive:

> MODELS: undefined

I need the models object to retrieve the data, but it is undefined. Why?

Comment: You're defining new app in datamodel.js. You only need to do `var app = express();` once in your application and pass the `app` variable to other modules so that they all refer to the same instance.

Comment: @Molda It works. Do you want to write an answer? I just do "var app = require('../app');" instead of "var app = express();" in file 2 and 3, and move "var app = express();" in file 1 two lines up, that it loads before the datamodel module.

Comment: I'll add an answer with the example of how it's usually done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining new app in datamodel.js. You only need to do `var app = express();` once in your application and pass the app variable to other modules so that they all refer to the same instance.

This is how it can be done:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// require the module and pass the `app` to the function it exports
require('./model/datamodel')(app);

app.use('/', require('./routes/api'));

module.exports = app;
```

datamodel.js

```
var orm = require('orm');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(orm.express("mysql://onserver:>2hZ[RpfCT~!xx@localhost/onserver", {
        define: function (db, models, next) {
            models.person = db.define("person", { 
                name      : String,
                surname   : String,
            } );

            next();
        }   
    }));
}
```

api.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(); 

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({ message: 'hoorayDATABASE: undefined! welcome to our api!' });  
});

router.post('/main', function( req, res ) { 
    console.log( "MODELS:", req.models );
})

module.exports = router;
```